# Emulator for iphone/ipod/ipad apps

Tags: ipod, iphone, apple, emulation, ipad

Is there any emulator for linux which fully supports apple iphone/iphone/ipad apps? Any other way to run such apps on linux?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579223/ipad-simulator-for-windows-or-ubuntu/10503214#10503214

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently the only emulator for testing iOS applications is build for MacOS.

> There is a work in process to bring an emulation software to linux
> which you might want to take a look at...but judging by the
> development status it'll be a while till it's usable.
> http://www.iemu.org/index.php/Main_Page

**EDIT**: This is outdated information. The project was discontinued some time in 2013.

Your options at this time would be to try and [install a hackintosh instance in virtualbox](https://www.hackint0sh.org/how-to-install-macos-on-virtualbox/) or use something like [Appetize.io](https://appetize.io/), if you have a bundled app that you want to try out.

For real productive development work I'm afraid you won't get around buying Apple hardware.

Comment: Is it legal to emulate ios apps? Installing osx(except server) in virtual box is illegal even in apple pc

Comment: If you would run a legal copy of MacOS from a virtualbox running on a MacBook for example it would be legal, even if the MacBooks OS would be Windows or linux. Because their user agreement says it is only legal to run MacOS on Apple hardware, which technically you do. Needless to say it's pretty pointless to emulate something you have natively. As for the iOS emulation, if you use Apples native emulator for Mac it is legal for development purposes.

Comment: Yeah I know but I heard that it is limitted to osx server edition

Comment: I think the iemu project is abandoned, see: http://phandroid.com/2011/09/16/iemu-open-source-ios-emulator-for-android-has-officially-been-cancelled-rip/  -- your link also doesn't work anymore... Is there any alternative?

Comment: @Tachyons Legal is one thing, ethical is another. Perfectly ethical.

Comment: The link is dead :(

Comment: yeeah I mean it's 8 years old :D